# Basic I/o token query

Tags: java, file, io, tokenize

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/Catalog.txt"));

    String line="";
    arrayList =new ArrayList();
    while((line = br.readLine())!=null)
        {
      //  System.out.println(line);
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
            //System.out.println(st.nextToken());
            arrayList.add(st.nextToken());
            }
        }
    }
```

//what is the use of token when reading the file? and what is an arraylist?

Comment: I would suggest you start reading a Java tutorial, from the beginning. Why Stack Overflow is good for answering specific questions, it's not good as a route to learning from scratch.

Comment: Id use a Scanner instead, but yea, read up on java API - google it

Answer (score 1):

The [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) is used to split every line in the file into words. The words are splitted at every space, tab character, newline character, carriage-return character and line-feed character.

An [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is an implementation of [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html), a collection of items that preserves their order. Every item in the list is accessible through a zero-based index.

I highly recommend to read the [Java 6 API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) for questions like this. It has every detail you need to know about the behaviour of standard Java classes.

Answer (score 0):

StringTokenizer will divide each line into words (tokenizes by space) and because of that ArrayList will have all the words present in that file.

Answer (score 0):

A tokenizer lets you break up the text by delimiters. Whitespace is used by default as delimiters, but you can also set these when you create a tokenizer. Just list them out in a string.

An arraylist is an expandable container for holding objects.